Tourist Entry to Spain - Accreditation of Financial Means
I'm trying to understand the financial documentation that meets the requirements for entry to Spain. I see this documentation on the government website

At the request of the competent authorities, the traveller must present proof of having sufficient financial means for the proposed stay, or of the ability to legally obtain such means.


In 2023, the minimum amount required is of $120 per person per day. In any case, and regardless of the length of stay, the traveller must have at least $1100 or its equivalent in foreign currency.


Financial means may be accredited by presenting cash, traveller's cheques, a credit card accompanied by a bank account statement, an up-to-date bank book, or any other resource that accredits the amount available, such as a credit statement regarding the card or bank account. Bank letters or online bank statements will not be accepted.​

My problem is that my main bank account gives statements every three months, and my most recent formal statement shows less than the $1,100 specified above. I've since receive my monthly income so my balance is above the specified amount, but I don't have a formal statement to that effect. Clearly, I can take a screen shot of my situation, from my online bank, but does that fall foul of the "online bank statements will not be accepted" clause? What would comprise a "or any other resource that accredits the amount available, such as a credit statement"
Any suggestions or experiences? Maybe the "online" prohibition means that I can't just show my phone to immigration, but a printout is OK? What did you do on entry to Spain?
I am not familiar with the term "credit statement" what form would that take?

Does your bank allow you to request a statement over and above the standard 3 month periodicity? Have you tried asking?

@Traveller good idea, and it worked. Thanks. I remain interested in what other forms of documentation would be deemed suitable.

I think the Spanish > English translation might be inaccurate. The original says”…o cualquier otro medio que acredite la cantidad disponible como crédito de la tarjeta o cuenta bancaria” without a comma after “disponible” (available). So it means “anything that proves the amount available as credit on the card or in the bank account”. Which could be eg a Certificate of Deposit, or a bond investment with a maturity date before the proposed travel date.

I'm now returned from the trip. I don't have a definitive picture as to what documentation would be accepted, so I'm not posting an answer. However, I can say that I, and seemingly every UK passenger on the plane presented just their passport and were granted entry with no questions or requests for other documentation.

Unsurprising. While of course travellers from the UK need to be aware of the rules, the UK press does love to whip up a storm over nothing.

I've literally never seen ANYONE questioned over this at immigration, and will bet heavily on it being dependent upon nationality.  I've never been asked any questions by immigration with a U.S. passport.  My guess is if you had a Morrocan passport, you might be asked for those documents.  I've lived and traveled all over, and it's quite often immigration is a subjectively applied law.
